# How to make the selection of text inside a TextField have a circular corner in flutter

Tags: flutter, textfield, flutter-web, selection

I would like the selection of text within a TextField to have rounded corners Does anyone know how to do that?

When I select the text inside a TextField, the highlight (in green color) - how to round the corners of it.

[image]

[image.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBqfJ.gif)

```
Container(
          width: 500,
          child: Theme(
            data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
              textSelectionTheme:
                  TextSelectionThemeData(selectionColor: Colors.green),
            ),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  "Email address",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontFamily: "Mitr",
                    fontSize: 18,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                  ),
                ),
                TextField(
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontFamily: "Mitr",
                    fontSize: 18,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                  ),
                  cursorColor: Colors.white,
                  cursorRadius: Radius.circular(15),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: 12.0,
                      horizontal: 12.0,
                    ),
                    isDense: true,
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white54,
                    ),
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide:
                          BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 1.0),
                    ),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide:
                          BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 2.0),
                    ),
                    hintText: 'name@example.com',
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: share some piece of code for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

Check if this package helps you achieve your goal; [rounded_background_text](https://pub.dev/packages/rounded_background_text)

Comment: It does not help. It highlights when writing the text, I am looking for something where when a user is highlighting via mouse/cursor inside a text field that should have rounded corners.